# How do I add a comma after each word in a list with a single long string of words in Python?

Tags: python

For example I have this list:

```
mylist=['I am fabulous']
```

And I want it to looks like this:

```
['I, am, fabulous']
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Can your list have more than one string in it? If so, what is the expected outcome? What if the string already has a comma in it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes I tried and I was searching for the answer. But none of them were related to Python.

Comment: you talk about lists but a list of one string is just a string, are you trying to get a list of words or just a string with spaces replaced with ', ', it looks like the second in your example but is that what you really want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split and rejoin it.

```
finallist = [ ", ".join(item.split(" ")) for item in mylist ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the space char with what you want.

```
mylist=['I am fabulous']

mylist[0] = mylist[0].replace(' ', ', ')

print mylist
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a string like

```
my_sentence = 'I am fabulous'
```

you can replace spaces i.e., `" "` with `", "`

```
print my_sentence.replace(" ", ", ")
```

**output:**

```
I, am, fabulous
```